# Multiple comparison, store result?

Tags: c#, performance

Whilst I was building an class to manage a somewhat tedious and repetitive process of displaying an `AlertDialog` in Android, I've stumbled upon this:

> Should I store into a var the result of a comparison and use it instead of making the same comparison *n* times?

In my case, I'm making the same comparison twice ( *the comparison will return always the same since between those comparisons I'm not changing anything that could change the result* ).

This is what I had:

```cs
public static AlertDialog BuildDialog( Activity activity, String header, String body, View view, DialogButton negative, DialogButton positive, DialogButton neutral ) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder( activity );

    alertDialogBuilder.SetTitle( header );
    alertDialogBuilder.SetMessage( body );

    if( view != null ) {
        alertDialogBuilder.SetView( view );
    }

    if( positive == null && negative == null && neutral == null ) {
        alertDialogBuilder.SetNeutralButton( "OK", (EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>) null );
    } else {
        if( negative != null ) {
            alertDialogBuilder.SetNegativeButton( negative.Text, negative.Action );
        }

        if( neutral != null ) {
            alertDialogBuilder.SetNeutralButton( neutral.Text, neutral.Action );
        }

        if( positive != null ) {
            alertDialogBuilder.SetPositiveButton( positive.Text, positive.Action );
        }
    }

    return alertDialogBuilder.Create();
}
```

And this is what I have now:

```cs
public static AlertDialog BuildDialog( Activity activity, String header, String body, View view, DialogButton negative, DialogButton positive, DialogButton neutral ) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder( activity );

    alertDialogBuilder.SetTitle( header );
    alertDialogBuilder.SetMessage( body );

    Boolean
        hasView = view != null,
        hasNeutral = neutral != null,
        hasPositive = positive != null,
        hasNegative = negative != null;

    if( hasView ) {
        alertDialogBuilder.SetView( view );
    }

    if( !hasNeutral && !hasPositive && !hasNegative ) {
        alertDialogBuilder.SetNeutralButton( "OK", (EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>) null );
    } else {
        if( hasNegative ) {
            alertDialogBuilder.SetNegativeButton( negative.Text, negative.Action );
        }

        if( hasNeutral ) {
            alertDialogBuilder.SetNeutralButton( neutral.Text, neutral.Action );
        }

        if( hasPositive ) {
            alertDialogBuilder.SetPositiveButton( positive.Text, positive.Action );
        }
    }

    return alertDialogBuilder.Create();
}
```

Although in this specific case shouldn't have a noticeable impact, which one does perform better and which one does read better?

Comment: Looks like you trying to micro-optimise your code. Are 20 nanoseconds faster than 40 nanoseconds? Try to make your code clean, simple and easy to read instead.

Comment: Even if I stick with @oleksii and would advice to make the code rather clean then overoptimize, anyway you can store you results as a bitmask and compare the bitmask if you want to :) But remember this might make the code even more unreadable.

Comment: As I've said, in this specific scenario there won't be any difference. This question was more about *if the variables being compared are so large that doing that way would be, or not, faster to do it* since it would be compared only once. Also, from my point of view, the code this way is somewhat faster to read and cleaner ( *although programmers read that naturally one way or another* ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null comparisons in .NET are very cheap, so the only reason to do something like that is readability, not execution speed. This is especially relevant for complex conditions, for example

```
bool nonNegative = hasPositive || hasNeutral;
...
if (nonNegative) ...
```

leads to more compact code that is easier to read.

Comment: Actually, now that I read your answer, null checking isn't that big deal, it just checks if the var is pointing to somewhere in the memory, right? Even though, as I've mentioned in a comment above, that way makes the code more easy to read, from my perspective.